# Python FTP won't Transfer

Tags: python, ftp

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but this small ftp code won't transfer files. I keep getting

File "example.py", line 11, in ?
    ftp.storlines("STOR " + file, open(file))

ftplib.error_perm: 550 /home/helen/docs/example.txt: Operation not permitted

Here is the code:

```
import ftplib

file = '/home/helen/docs/example.txt'     
ftp = ftplib.FTP('domain', 'user', 'password')
print "File List: "
files = ftp.dir()

ftp.cwd("/upload/")

ftp.storlines("STOR " + file, open(file))

f.close()                               
s.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the error you're getting is that you're adding the entire file path to the first argument in the`storlines()`call. Instead, just specify the file name itself:

```
import os
ftp.storlines("STOR " + os.path.basename(file), open(file))
```

You might want to consider changing`file`to`filepath`,since that's what it really is (plus you will no longer be hiding the built-in function & type of the same name).

Comment: Thanks @martineau - I will check my code when I get back to the office on Monday. Don't have access to the server from home.

Comment: @Helen: Oops, my original answer was completely on the wrong track. Try the revised version when you have a chance.

Comment: thanks for the tip. just calling the file name instead of the entire path did the trick. Awesome stuff. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

550 error literally means according to wikipedia "550   Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes

are you sure you have the right permissions?

try this

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('domain')
ftp.login('user','pass')
```

i think the object creation was just a little jacked up.

Comment: I do have the relevant permissions - the ftp directory has been given 777 permissions. Which means anyone can upload and read (just for testing)

Comment: is it a public or private ftp? is the domain entered correctly? if you are getting a 550, it thinks something is wrong.... lemme check something out real quick....
try `ftp = ftplib.FTP('domain')` THEN `ftp.login('user','pass')` i think you are actually trying to log into nothing, which would be a good reason for a 550

Comment: Hey, @Teh, thanks. Will try your suggestion on Monday and let everyone know the result.